# Does falling temp. reach all interim temperatures?

Tags: temperature

Does a plummeting temperature reach all temperatures in between its initial temperature and its final temperature?

Comment: Yep, by the intermediate value theorem and the fact that temperature depends continuously on time.

Comment: If I may ask the OP: Could you suggest a situation where this would not be true?

Comment: -1. No effort. What do you think about this? What prompted you to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Since temperature is not quantized, the temperature of a system you've described should pass every real number between the initial temperature and the final temperature.

Comment: Are you really claiming "any real number"? Already "any rational number" would be a very strong claim, difficult to prove.

Comment: @Pieter, I'd say it's infinitely more likely for a temperature to be any non-rational real number than for it to be any rational number. Temperature can be any real number.

Comment: Physical systems are limited in size. The internal energy should be quantized in principle. The number of microstates should be countable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with answering this question is that any system will have a statistical fluctuating "temperature" even though the fluctuations might be small.
So defining an exact temperature for the whole of a system is impossible as is an exact initial and final temperature.
The best one can do is have some sort of average temperature.

In practical terms because you are dealing with an overage over a very large number of particles one can say that temperature is not quantised.